# Are PHP label names reserved globally?

Tags: php, closures, label, goto

I know `goto` won't work between functions and classes, but are the label names reserved? Can I successfully use the same label name in separate closures?

Comment: Have you tried it for yourself?

Comment: What's a PHP label name?

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote? @Tim Cooper: If everyone had to try everything themselves then the value of Googling would violently drop. @John Green: The name of a PHP label?

Comment: @Codemonkey: This is something quite easy to test, though. Perhaps if you had tried it and it DIDN'T work, then there would be a better question. It usually helps when you have at least have some code included.

Comment: Asking this question deserves a downvote? @Tim Cooper: Sure I could install and configure PHP and Apache, create a PHP file, write the code and test it out for myself. But wouldn't finding the answer on the internet save me a load of time?

Comment: @Codemonkey: When you're posting a question about PHP, I guess it's assumed that you have the PHP interpretor installed. This allows you to test code you, in this case, should have had written before hand to help out anyone that is trying to assist you with your question. It just makes it easier. Next time!

Comment: I still don't think what I should have done beforehand justifies a downvote. Downvotes generally means "bad question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = function()
{
    goto end;
    end:
    echo "From X\n";
};

$y = function()
{
    goto end;
    end:
    echo "From Y\n";
};

$x();
$y();
/*
Outputs:

From X
From Y
*/
```